# The insert statement conflict error in mvc code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please help me .. I tried myself but couldn't find the solution..
I am getting this error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.BookHotels_dbo.Rooms_RoomID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "IncrediblePakistan.Models.MyDbContext", table "dbo.Rooms",
>   column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a room into the Rooms table? You must have a valid hotel "ID" within that INSERT statement. That will cause this error. The constraint causes this error when the FK is not valid in the table being inserted to. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thankx for you reply sir.. Actually I am making a Hotel Room booking system in my website. there is one to many relation between Room and BookHotel model.. for that I have added public int RoomID , public virtual Room Room{get;set;} in BookHotel model and added icollection of BookHotel in Room table..